# Grouped Product Options Magento Wishlist

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.9

When adding a Grouped Product to the Wishlist in Magento, you are unable to add the individual products.  You can only click "click add to cart" and it takes you back to the individual product detail page to then add them product qty's individually.

How I can show the individual Grouped Product qtys on the Wishlist page?